# Is there a way for wordpress to share a flask cookie set by Flask-Login?

Tags: php, wordpress, flask, flask-login

I have a Flask app hosted at xyz.com and now I would like to move it to app.xyz.com (it will also have login and signup pages at app.xyz.com/login and app.xyz.com/signup, managed by [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/)). I would like to now direct xyz.com to a Wordpress website, with the home page showing the login and signup buttons. But for a user that is already logged in to app.xyz.com, I would like to hide these buttons and simply have a button called 'Go to Dashboard'.

How can I get the Wordpress website at xyz.com to know if the user is already logged in at app.xyz.com?

I tried to send a get parameter from app.xyz.com with `?loggedin=True`, but I wasn't able to get the required javascript in wordpress to switch the 'Login' and 'Sign up' buttons with 'Go to Dashboard' when the user was logged in.